# Highlight certain rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select certain rows in a pivot table and highlight them using vba. I have been trying a few things, but I have only been able to highlight one cell. The below code isn't working, but maybe a few tweaks to it will fix it. I need to do this in vba and not use conditional formatting.

Edit: Improved code using suggestion from answer below and own knowledge. It is still not working correctly though.

```
Sub Highlight()


Dim fnd As Variant

fnds = Array("abc", "dfy", "zxc")


For i = 0 To UBound(fnds)

Cells.Find(What:=(fnds), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False).Activate
With Selection.EntireRow.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using .Find you are only finding the first instance of each element of the array fnds, is this what you are wanting? I think you are after every occurrence in which case we need to put a loop in there.

Also personal preference here but I prefer to create reference to the cells / rows / columns to be manipulated then only do the actual manipulation once. Not such a biggy when you are only shading but when making changes such as deletions and updates it can be a massive process time saver.

```
Sub Highlight()
Dim i As Long, DelRange As String
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "abc") <> 0 Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "dfy") <> 0 Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "zxc") <> 0 Then DelRange = DelRange & "," & i & ":" & i
Next i
With Range(Right(DelRange, Len(DelRange) - 1)).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `Rows` collection you are making reference to. Instead you probably want `EntireRow` of the selected range.

```
With Selection.EntireRow.Interior
   .Pattern = xlSolid
   ...
```

Comment: Seems to be closer, but still not getting the expected behaviour. It is highlighting rows around the first find and stopping there.

Comment: Stick that `With` block inside of your `For` block so that it can be part of the iteration through your `DelRange`'s